# distanceTo() integer overflow?

Tags: java, integer, integer-overflow

This is my method to determine the distance between two points:

```
    // Euclidean distance between this point and that point
    public int distanceTo(Point that) {
        int distanceX = this.x - that.x;
        int distanceY = this.y - that.y;
        return (int) Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);
    }
```

Is it possible that an integer overflow occurs, and if so, how can I prevent it?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: The answer depends on which coordinates you are using for x and y. If they are guaranteed to be small enough, there is no risk of integer overflow.

Comment: They are also integers but it can still come to an overflow, right?

Comment: if the square root is more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, yes

Comment: They seem to represent 2D coordinates. Can the difference between two x (or y) coordinates be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`? If the answer is true, your method should perform subtraction of longs, and also return a long.

Comment: (x,y) is a Point where both x and y are 32-bit integers. The distance between two points can be bigger than 2^{31}-1. How can I throw an Exception if the distance is not a valid 32-bit integer?

Comment: by "not a valid 32-bit integer", do you mean "if the square root is more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`" ?

Comment: Yes. Can I check that via `if (Math.sqrt(...) > Integer.MAX_VALUE) { throw ... }`?

Comment: of course you can

Comment: @jhamon please see my edit

Comment: an `int` can never be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. But you can write your condition as `Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY) > Integer.MAX_VALUE`. But beware - for `int distanceX, distanceY` the argument `distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY` is calculated using integer arithmetic. You should define distanceX and distanceY as long or double.

Comment: @ThomasKläger See my edit on my original question. It doesn't seem to work

Comment: it doesn't seem to work because you cast `Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY)` to an `int` first and only then do the comparison - just remove the cast `(int)` from your `if ((int) Math.sqrt(..) > Integer.MAX_VALUE)`, i.e. write  `if (Math.sqrt(..) > Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent incorrect result from overflow, use the `Math` "exact" methods:

- [`Math.addExact(int x, int y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#addExact-int-int-)<sup>1</sup>
- [`Math.subtractExact(int x, int y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#subtractExact-int-int-)<sup>1</sup>
- [`Math.multiplyExact(int x, int y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact-int-int-)<sup>1</sup>
- [`Math.incrementExact(int a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#incrementExact-int-)<sup>1</sup>
- [`Math.decrementExact(int a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#decrementExact-int-)<sup>1</sup>
- [`Math.negateExact(int a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#negateExact-int-)<sup>1</sup>
- [`Math.toIntExact(long value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact-long-)

<sup>*1) Or the `long` variant.*</sup>

The methods will throw an `ArithmeticException` if overflow would have occurred.

```
public int distanceTo(Point that) throws ArithmeticException {
    int distanceX = Math.subtractExact(this.x, that.x);
    int distanceY = Math.subtractExact(this.y, that.y);
    return (int) Math.sqrt(Math.addExact(Math.multiplyExact(distanceX, distanceX),
                                         Math.multiplyExact(distanceY, distanceY)));
}
```

Of course it might be prudent to use `long` math to minimize the probability of overflow.

```
public int distanceTo(Point that) {
    long distanceX = Math.subtractExact((long) this.x, (long) that.x);
    long distanceY = Math.subtractExact((long) this.y, (long) that.y);
    long sumOfSquares = Math.addExact(Math.multiplyExact(distanceX, distanceX),
                                      Math.multiplyExact(distanceY, distanceY));
    return Math.toIntExact((long) Math.sqrt(sumOfSquares));
}
```

There might be a small loss of precision when `sumOfSquares` is widened to a `double`, but the effect would likely be lost when decimals are discarded during cast to `long`.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. (However, the cast to long for `distanceX` and `distanceY` is redundant because Widening Conversion takes place)

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake Without casting at least one of them, it'll call the `int subtractExact(int x, int y)` overload and widen the result, not the `long subtractExact(long x, long y)` where it widens before the subtraction and can handle e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE` without causing overflow.

Comment: OK. I tried it without doing the cast at the boundary values and it worked. In addition, IntelliJ Idea tells me that it doesn’t change the result in any way and it’s therefore redundant. Should I still type cast it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to confuse you. I meant the type cast (long) for distanceX and distanceY. That won't change anything, right? So I can just use long `distanceX = Math.subtractExact(this.x, that.x);`?

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake As I already said, without the cast the `int` version of the method is called. E.g. if `this.x = 2000000000` and `that.x = -1000000000`, then `Math.subtractExact((long) this.x, (long) that.x)` will return the `long` value `3000000000` *(`>Integer.MAX_VALUE`)*, and `Math.subtractExact(this.x, that.x)` will throw `ArithmeticException: integer overflow`

Comment: I am not entirely sure but I think the `long subtractExact()` method is used, even if it's not type-casted to `long` because the variable distanceX/distanceY is a `long`. Nonetheless, I will still add the typecast to be sure. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake You are wrong. When parameters are `int`, the `int` version is called, and the result is then widened to `long`.

Comment: OK. I am just a big surprised that IntelliJ IDEA tells me that it's redundant. Usually this is correct

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake 1 of the 2 casts is redundant.

Comment: Should I add `throws ArithmeticException` to the signature of the method? It seems to work without it but should it still be added?

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake That is entirely up to you. Is it important for the caller, i.e. would the caller ever want to catch it. My guess is no, so it's not important information. If this is for a third-party library, then documenting it with javadoc might be appropriate, otherwise I wouldn't. I just showed it so you knew you could if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use the [**hypotenuse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotenuse) function.

Then integer overflow may happen at a distance (`-`).

The solution is to use double, as the the final result is calculated using a floating point function.

The result could be as large as `sqrt(2)*2*Integer.MAX_VALUE`, also overflowing.

So:

```
public int distanceTo(Point that) {
    double distanceX = ((double)this.x) - that.x;
    double distanceY = ((double)this.y) - that.y;
    double distance = Math.hypot(distanceX, distanceY);
    if (distance + 1 >= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("Integer overflow");
    }
    return (int) distance; // (int) Math.round?
}
```

Or neater (as did Andreas):

```
public int distanceTo(Point that) {
    double distanceX = ((double)this.x) - that.x;
    double distanceY = ((double)this.y) - that.y;
    double distance = Math.hypot(distanceX, distanceY);
    return Math.toIntExact((long)distance); // (int) Math.round?
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your second method is shorter than Andreas'. Does it still work the exact same way?

Comment: Leave the voting as is - the difference is minor, and my answer was later. Using hypot there is no overflow on x & y distances for my solution. x dist 2*MAX, y dist MAX/2/sqrt(2) would work for my answer. And of course using "hypotenuse" flatters one's self esteem.